# VHDL error - STD logic type is not known

Tags: vhdl

I built a block diagram in VHDL. I keep getting the following error, when I try to compile.

```
line 15: Error, 'std_logic' is not a known type.
line 16: Error, 'std_logic_vector' is not a known type.
```

Most answers on Google say that it could be a problem with IEEE library or other packages...

I have the following libraries in my design:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;"
```

I do not understand why it keeps giving me an error. I thought that using `LIBRARY ieee` is sufficient to take care of `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector`.

Comment: Line 15 and 16 refer to two inputs. One is std logic, and the other is std_logic_vector

Comment: Please post your failing code, since the provided information is not enough.

Comment: I have a block diagram . Here are lines 15 and 16( from the auto generated code).                                                                                                                ENTITY Lab9DecodeStageDP IS
   PORT( 
      Clock1  : IN     std_logic;
      D2      : IN     std_logic_vector (15 DOWNTO 0);

Comment: Until you post a suitable example we can only guess. My guess is that the library/use clauses are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what is wrong from your description. A small code snippet would help. Just so you know, `library ieee;` is only sufficient to make the `ieee` library available. Without a `use` statement you have to prefix everything from that library with `ieee.<foo>`. You do have `use` statements though, so that isn't the problem. I'd suggest trying a minimal test case to ensure your tools are setup correctly and there are no syntax errors confusing them. If you aren't doing this with a simulator then switch to one because they give better error reports. Also note that `std_logic_arith` is not an IEEE standard package and you should be using `ieee.numeric_std` or `ieee.std_logic_unsigned` instead. Don't use them if you aren't doing arithmetic with the built-in operators.

Comment: I have a block diagram . Here are lines 15 and 16( from the auto generated code). ENTITY Lab9DecodeStageDP IS PORT( Clock1 : IN std_logic; D2 : IN std_logic_vector (15 DOWNTO 0);

Comment: @khalid You have to provide everything before that entity to determine what the problem is.

Comment: well, I have already done everything you guys said before posting the question. I closed the program multiple times and opened it again, but still got the same error. A couple of hours later, however, the block diagram compiled correctly!!!! It is working fine now. Thanks